# deployApp Error building shinyEvents (2.1)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have absolutely no trouble utilizing runApp() from the shiny library. Everything works fine and I can work on my app. Yet, if I try to run deployApp() I always get denied when trying to build shinyEvents (2.1).

The error msg is somewhat similar to this overstackflow thread: [deployApp Error building taskscheduleR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739488/deployapp-error-building-taskscheduler)

Unfortunately the answer doesn't really provide my with much insights, as I canno't swap the shinyEvents library in exchange for another - I'm writing a RTutor problemset for my thesis and this package depends on shinyEvents.

This is my specific error:

> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 363233459 failed: Error building image:
>   Error building shinyEvents (2.1). Build exited with non-zero status: 1

What I did so far was trying to reinstall multiple libraries, aswell as trying different versions of both R and RStudio. I also tried to manually publish it via RStudio, when running the app, the same error occurs. I tried different computers and wiping R completely - nothing seems to work.

There is also a complete log I can provide:

```
> library(rsconnect)
> deployApp(appName="RTutorOnlineDisclosure")
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 167013...DONE
Deploying bundle: 762809 for application: 167013 ...
Waiting for task: 363233458
building: Parsing manifest
building: Building image: 752009
building: Installing system dependencies
building: Fetching packages
building: Building package: shinyEvents
Begin Task Log 
[2017-03-25T12:13:00.601152176+0000] Execute script: packages/build/V8.sh
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
libv8-3.14.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libv8-3.14.5 libv8-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4628 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libv8-    3.14.5 amd64 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 [1189 kB]
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libv8-dev amd64 3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2 [57.6 kB]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
Fetched 1247 kB in 0s (36.0 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libv8-3.14.5.
(Reading database ... 103066 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libv8-3.14.5_3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libv8-3.14.5 (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libv8-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libv8-dev_3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libv8-dev (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libv8-3.14.5 (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libv8-dev (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
[2017-03-25T12:13:14.897318682+0000] Installing R package: sourcetools (0.1.5)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘sourcetools’ ...
* DONE (sourcetools)
[2017-03-25T12:13:15.258827517+0000] Installing R package: stringi (1.1.3)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘stringi’ ...
* DONE (stringi)

LOTS OF INSTALLATIONS.....

[2017-03-25T12:13:25.538176973+0000] Installing R package: data.table (1.10.4)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘data.table’ ...
* DONE (data.table)
[2017-03-25T12:13:25.959408111+0000] Installing R package: lmtest (0.9-35)
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘lmtest’ ...
* DONE (lmtest)
[2017-03-25T12:13:26.2253965 End Task Log  
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 363233459 failed: Error building image:
Error building shinyEvents (2.1). Build exited with non-zero status: 1##
```